# Masm32: SetConsoleTextAttribute

Tags: winapi, masm32

I am newbie in assembler. I need to change text color in loop (5 time - 5 different colors) using Masm32. My code:

```
Main PROC
    LOCAL hStdout:DWORD
    call SetConsoleTitleA
    push -11
    call GetStdHandle
    mov hStdout,EAX

    mov BX,5
        lp:

        push hStdout
        push 2
        call SetConsoleTextAttribute

        push 0
        push 0
        push 24d
        push offset sWriteText
        push hStdout
        call WriteConsoleA

        dec BX
    jnz lp

    push 2000d
    call Sleep

    push 0
    call ExitProcess

    Main ENDP
end Main
```

P.S. Sorry for my Enlish.

Comment: You forgot to write a question. Assuming, that you are expecting to see different colors, but aren't, I'd recommend reading [SetConsoleTextAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047.aspx). Passing `2` as the *wAttributes* parameter doesn't magically set a different text color for each call.

Comment: Are you sure they're passing 2 as `wAttributes`?

Comment: I don't know how to use this function

Comment: You might want to start by calling SetConsoleTitle correctly.

Comment: Is this wrong calling?

Comment: When you call `SetConsoleTitle` you haven't pushed any arguments onto the stack.  Specifically `lpConsoleTitle`. See also: [`__stdcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) and [`SetConsoleTitle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: As pointed out by @theB, the `__stdcall` calling convention demands, that arguments must be pushed **right to left** onto the stack. For `SetConsoleTextAttributes` you need to first push *wAttributes*, followed by *hConsoleOutput*. The damage, however, starts, when you're calling `SetConsoleTitleA` without pushing anything onto the stack. It's working off of random data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem 1

As hinted to by Raymond Chen is that the call to [`SetConsoleTitle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is incorrect.

```
Main PROC
    LOCAL hStdout:DWORD
    call SetConsoleTitleA
```

Notice that you don't push any arguments onto the stack for `SetConsoleTitle`.  This means that after this call the stack is corrupted.

Once this is fixed we can move on to problem 2.

#### Problem #2

According to the [`__stdcall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28vs.71%29.aspx) calling convention arguments are pushed right-to-left. But in the code the arguments are being pushed left-to-right. In the code above this is the call sequence for [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047.aspx)

```
push hStdout
push 2
call SetConsoleTextAttribute
```

Given the function's signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleTextAttribute(
  _In_ HANDLE hConsoleOutput,
  _In_ WORD   wAttributes
);
```

The code is calling this function like the following C code,

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(2, hStdout);
```

which is reversed. The call should be:

```
push 2
push hStdout
call SetConsoleTextAttribute
```

#### Problem 3

The code ignores all return values, except for `GetStdHandle`.  For `SetConsoleTextAttribute` the return value is nonzero if the function was successful.  If the function returns zero, then the function call failed, and *for this function*<sup>1</sup> extended error information is available by calling `GetLastError`. The documentation on MSDN has information about each of the other functions and how they indicate errors.

---

*<sup>1</sup>Not all functions call `SetLastError` when they fail. There are a lot of issues caused by thinking otherwise. Also of note that functions that do set the error, only do so when they have an error.*

*Also worth a read is [The History Of Calling Conventions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=the%20history%20of%20calling%20conventions&beta=0&rn=The+Old+New+Thing&rq=site:blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/&ac=4) series over at The Old New Thing.*